# Xam.Geolocation.Plugin not working on my android app

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, api, xamarin

I am trying to access the current location of my device in a Xamarin forms app I am using the Geolocation plugin created by James Montemagno. I have added a reference in my pcl and platform project but every time my app hits the bold line of code I get a `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.` I have also added all the necessary settings in the android manifest.

```
 var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

 locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100;
```

**var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);**

**Here is StackTrace**

> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002d] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:193
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult
>   () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:580
>   at
>   Plugin.Geolocator.GeolocatorImplementation+<GetPositionAsync>d__27.MoveNext
>   () [0x00597] in
>   G:\GitHub\Xamarin.Plugins\Geolocator\Geolocator\Geolocator.Plugin.Android\GeolocatorImplementation.cs:195
>   at --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00027] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:190
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult ()
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372
>   at NetJetApp.Views.Home+d__52.MoveNext () [0x0003e] in
>   c:\svn\Netjet\trunk\NetJetXamarin\NetJet\NetJetApp\NetJetApp\Views\Home.cs:552
>   at --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00027] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:190
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult ()
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372
>   at NetJetApp.Views.Home+d__49.MoveNext () [0x00111] in
>   c:\svn\Netjet\trunk\NetJetXamarin\NetJet\NetJetApp\NetJetAp   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455p\Views\Home.cs:532   at ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.m__0
>   (System.Object state) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:994
>   at Android.App.SyncContext+c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:18
>   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36
>   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr
>   native__this) [0x00009] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:71
>   at at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:089044c0-4139-4792-8365-3f98e93136b3 (intptr,intptr)

Comment: A couple of things to try, even if only to rule them out. Have you tried a smaller `DesiredAccuracy`? Our apps use 50. Does the code check `locator.IsGeolocationEnabled` first?

Comment: I tried 50 but i find no win , no i did'nt do the check where should i do it

Comment: I'll go ahead and post an answer with the code we are using.

Comment: I have managed to get the exception you are running into, while running the code in my answer in Visual Studio 2013 debugger using Android device. My perception while waiting for a breakpoint to inspect position is that the call to GetCurrentLocation took more than 10 second. If so that would have tripped the timeout and may have caused the task cancellation. I'll shorten the timeout to see if I can get more consistent failures.

Comment: A shorter timeout definitely increases the likelihood of the TaskCanceledException. At 1000 the exception is occurring almost every time. I modified my answer a bit, hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Mark this helped me a lot, with the exception handling i was able to see that the app could'nt read permission from the manifest and i research on cause of this exception and i found i needed to add  CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity; on my mainActivity class as it is done here https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Media/MediaAndroidTest/MainApplication.cs . But sometimes it runs smootly and sometime crasshes again

Comment: If the app is still crashing, I think there must be another unhandled exception somewhere else. As far as geolocation goes, in the apps where we need location, we also understand that sometimes the device cannot or will not (because of user decision on settings) be able to provide this, so we use this code in the app, and then also handle it (flag location absence whether null or 0, 0) on the server side. Good luck!

Comment: We have increased the timeout from 10 to 15 seconds. iOS seemed to consistently get position in under 10, but Android not as consistent. Raising to 15 seconds has made it consistent for both, no observed task cancelled exceptions in logs for several days.

Comment: Thank you Mark i have managed to get it working by trying to get the location before i use it. previously i was getting the position when a button is clicked on  a page with to many tasks running so now am getting the location on the page constructor and store it on Global static variable

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, there is a definite correlation between the GetPositionAsync timeout expiry and the TaskCanceledException, so a larger value could reduce the likelihood of that exception. I definitely want to thank you for your question, because it made me look into this code in our framework more closely.

For sure, the app code needs to handle the reality that the device may not be able to provide position in a reasonable amount of time, for any number of reasons.

To help with the crash, the code below is in a Xamarin.Forms PCL project, used from Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS projects whose apps are in the app stores.

There are no essential differences between this and what you posted, other than the check for IsGeolocationEnabled and the exception handling, but with that exception handling and the debug statements hopefully it prevents app crash and helps you get further along.

```
public static async Task<Position> GetCurrentLocation()
{
    // Capture the current location.
    Position position = null;
    try
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

        // Get the current device position. Leave it null if geo-location is disabled,
        // return position (0, 0) if unable to acquire.
        if (locator.IsGeolocationEnabled)
        {
            // Allow ten seconds for geo-location determination.                    
            position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(10000);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Location could not be acquired, geolocator is disabled.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception le)
    {
        // TODO: Log this error.
        Debug.WriteLine("Location could not be acquired.");
        Debug.WriteLine(le.Message);
        Debug.WriteLine(le.StackTrace);
        position = new Position() { Latitude = 0, Longitude = 0 };
    }

    return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using a shared Xamarin.Forms library.
I solved it on iOS, but I am still working on the Android version.

**Note**: It is necessary to include the Xam.Plugin.Geolocator package in all the projects

I hope this code can help you

---

In the shared library I have the following:

- App.xaml
- App.xaml.cs
- MyAppPage.xaml
- MyAppPage.xaml.cs

In the iOS Library I changed only the

- AppDelegate.cs

---

File Contents:

- Changes in App.xaml.cs

  ```
  public App(IGeolocator geolocator)
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      MainPage = new MySpeedPage(geolocator);
  }
  ```
- MyAppPage.xaml.cs

  ```
  public partial class MyAppPage : ContentPage
  {
      readonly IGeolocator geolocator;

      public MyAppPage(IGeolocator geolocator)
      {
          InitializeComponent();
          this.geolocator = geolocator;
          this.geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
          this.geolocator.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<PositionEventArgs>(OnGeolocatorPositionChanged);
      }

      void OnGeolocatorPositionChanged(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
      {
          LabLatitude.Text = String.Format("Lat: {0:F4}", e.Position.Latitude);
          LabLongitude.Text = String.Format("Lon: {0:F4}", e.Position.Longitude);
      }

      void OnBtnStartClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
      {
          BtnStart.IsEnabled = false;
          BtnStop.IsEnabled = true;
          geolocator.StartListeningAsync(2500, 10.0f, true);
      }

      void OnBtnStopClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
      {
          BtnStart.IsEnabled = true;
          BtnStop.IsEnabled = false;
          geolocator.StopListeningAsync();
      }

   }
  ```
- Changes in "AppDelegate.cs"

  ```
  public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
  {
      global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

      var MyApp = new App(CrossGeolocator.Current);
      LoadApplication(MyApp);

      return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
  }
  ```